# Provide Kubernetes cluster authentication with kubeconfig over https

Tags: rest, authentication, kubernetes, https, kubeconfig

I have a kubernetes cluster. I created the cluster using the `Google Cloud`, but not using the GKE, but using GCE. I've created one `master node` and two `worker nodes` using `VM instances`. `Kubeadm` is used for joining the master and worker nodes along with `kube-flannel.yml` file. I am exposing my cluster outside in `postman` using my `Vm's public ip & nodePort`. I am able to hit to that URL. `publicip:nodePort/adapter_name`. The hit is reaching my pods and logs are generating. When I used `minikube` before, I've used `port-forwarding` to expose my port. Now i am not using that.

There is a default `kubeconfig` file called config is present in the location `$HOME/.kube/config`. It have the following content in it.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUM1ekNDQWMrZ0F3SUJ....
    server: https://10.128.0.12:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSURFe....
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQpNSUlFb.....
```

The server `IP` is `https://10.128.0.12:6443`. Can I change this default URL to the one required for authentication[my rest api url]??

My requirement is to provide authentication for my rest api url, that my application enables, while running in the kubernetes pod.

How can I authenticate my rest api url with this `kubeconfig` method or by creating a new  kubeconfig file and using that??

https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/cluster-administration/authenticate-across-clusters-kubeconfig/

http://docs.shippable.com/deploy/tutorial/create-kubeconfig-for-self-hosted-kubernetes-cluster/

I got few ideas from above two blogs and tried to implement that, but none of them is satisfying my requirement. Authentication via postman using any JWT token is also acceptable.

Kubernetes version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.4", GitCommit:"d360454c9bcd1634cf4cc52d1867af5491dc9c5f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-11-11T13:17:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} 
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.4", GitCommit:"d360454c9bcd1634cf4cc52d1867af5491dc9c5f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-11-11T13:09:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: This cluster is on your local environment? What Kubernetes version are you using. Its Kubeadm or Minikube? How will you expose your cluster outside?

Comment: i created the cluster using the Google cloud,but not using the GKE. I created one master node and two worker nodes using vm instances. Kubeadm is used for joining the master and worker nodes along with kube-flannel.yml file. I am exposing my cluster outside in postman using my Vm's public ip & nodePort. I am able to hit to that URL. publicip:nodePort/adapter_name. The hit is reaching my pods and logs are generating. When i used minikube before, i used port forwarding to expose my port. Now i am not using that

Comment: Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.4", GitCommit:"d360454c9bcd1634cf4cc52d1867af5491dc9c5f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-11-11T13:17:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.4", GitCommit:"d360454c9bcd1634cf4cc52d1867af5491dc9c5f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-11-11T13:09:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: Please edit your question and add additional information from comments. It's better to read all informatios from Question section than from comments. Just to clarify some facts. You want to expose POD/service/authentication to external, if so, how would youlike to authenticate? Or do you want your pod/api send request to kubernetes api? Are you looking for something like [Access Clusters Using the Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/)

Comment: Hi, I editetd the question with the above details. Yeah, @PjoterS i am expecting the authentication like this. Service account token method i tried a lot of times,but failed. I took the JWT token from the secret which is created along with the serviceaccounset. Just like in the doc, i used that token as Bearer token in postman when i hit my url. But no authentication enabled

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/ this is one i referred

Comment: Just to clarify one thing, did you create some certificates, or you are looking the best way to secure your cluster?

Comment: yes, the best way i can secure my rest adapters

Comment: can i use any third party security like istio for the same??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method to authenticate our client api/end point url is to use `Istio`

[Istio installation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/)

I documeneted whole process of providing security via Istio in a PDF file which i am attaching [here](https://pdfhost.io/v/emsAoXAbr_Istio_Installation_Integration_and_Security_with_Kubernetes_Cluster_Open_sourcepdf.pdf). Istio is used for the verification of the token and Keycloak is used for the generation of the JWT Token.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as `Community Wiki`.

#### I. Accesing Kubernetes API.

> Can I change this default URL (cluster server IP address) to the one required for authentication my rest api url??

I **wouldn't recommend this**. `KUBECONFIG` files are used to organize information about clusters, users, namespaces,  authentication mechanisms and to store information about your connection to the Kubernetes cluster. When you use kubectl to execute commands, it gets the correct communication information from this `KUBECONFIG`.

In `KUBECONFIG` you can authenticate using `X509 Client Certs` or different types of `Tokens`. More details can be found in [Authentication strategies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#without-kubectl-proxy) and [Access Clusters Using the Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/)

If you are interested how to access **kubernetes API** using Beare Token, please check [this docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#without-kubectl-proxy).

#### II. Accesing Client API

If you want to expose your endpoint rest api as public, you could use:

- [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)

> Exposes the Service on each Node's IP at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP Service, to which the NodePort Service routes, is automatically created. You'll be able to contact the NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting :.

- [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer)

> Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider's load balancer. NodePort and ClusterIP Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created.

**Note:** For bare metal env, consider using use [Metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/)

Kubernetes does not offer an implementation of network load-balancers (Services of type LoadBalancer) for bare metal clusters. The implementations of Network LB that Kubernetes does ship with are all glue code that calls out to various IaaS platforms (GCP, AWS, Azure…). If you’re not running on a supported IaaS platform (GCP, AWS, Azure…), LoadBalancers will remain in the “pending” state indefinitely when created.

Once you expose your api to the outside of the world (if necessary)

- you can use mutual TLS authentication between your client and sever(api) endpoint.
- you can use [Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) with [External OAUTH Authentication](https://learnk8s.io/microservices-authentication-kubernetes)

As alternative solution, you could consider [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) as additional authentication with [Gatekeeper](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_keycloak_generic_adapter) in rest api as sidecare which verify if there was authentication.

If you would interested in authentications between microservices you can check [Authentication between microservices using Kubernetes identities](https://learnk8s.io/microservices-authentication-kubernetes) article.

If you are interested with istio, please take a look at [Istio Security](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/security/)
Istio provides two types of authentication:

- **Peer authentication:** used for service-to-service authentication to verify the client making the connection
- **Request authentication:** Used for end-user authentication to verify the credential attached to the request. Istio enables request-level authentication with JSON Web Token (JWT) validation and a streamlined developer experience using a custom authentication provider or any OpenID Connect providers -
  [example](https://mymusictaste.github.io/end-user-auth-with-istio-keycloak-eks/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reply. It covered all areas of my Question and cleared few confusions also. I moved with the `Istio End user-authentication` method to provide security to my **client (Rest) API.** I will post my method here as another answer with all the steps.